# Why is the destructor being called three times?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

**Input:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class SimpleClass
{
    public:

    SimpleClass()
    {
        cout<<"SimpleClass Constructor\n";
    }
    virtual ~SimpleClass()
    {
        cout<<"SimpleClass destructor\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    SimpleClass a;    
    SimpleClass lol = a;

    SimpleClass b;
    SimpleClass * lol2 = &b;
}
```

**Output:**

```
SimpleClass Constructor
SimpleClass Constructor
SimpleClass destructor
SimpleClass destructor
SimpleClass destructor
```

I am confused why the destructor is being called 3 times.

### The Constructor is only called twice!!!!

Comment: you have 3 objects, right? `a, lol, b`. How many destructor calls do you expect? If you implement `copy constructor`, you will see one object is copied.

Comment: How many times did you expect?

Comment: I expected 2 times. Because the `lol` constructor is not called.

Comment: Question should be "Why are there only 2 calls to Constructor?"

Comment: @mk1 No, the *copy constructor* is called for `lol`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The destructor is being called three times, for `a`, `lol` and `b`.
In your case, `a` and `b` are instantiated using the `default constructor`. However note that `lol` is instantiated using the `copy constructor`

Answer (score 6):

Because there are exactly 3 objects of class SimpleClass created, but your constructor is called only 2 times:

- 1st object is `a`, calls your constructor;
- 2nd is `lol`, which is initialized by copying from **a** via an **implicitly defined copy constructor**  (thus bypassing your constructor);
- 3rd is `b`, calls your constructor.

Note that `lol2` is just a pointer to b, so no extra calls are made.

And the correct name is "destructor", not "deconstructor" ;)

Comment: Can you overload this implicitly defined copy constructor?

Comment: Yes, you can define it explicitly as SimpleClass(const SimpleClass& other). But there's one caveat here: the compiler is allowed to optimize away the call when it is safe to do so. This is why the copy constructor generally shouldn't have any side effects (writing to cout is a side effect). Turn off compiler optimizations if your copy constructor doesn't output anything.

Comment: @AlexJenter: But if the copy constructor call is optimized away (and it won't be in this case), the destructor will be also, so constructor calls will still == destructor calls.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: That's correct, thanks for useful addition. I didn't mean that it will be optimized in this example, it was a general warning that this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

You've got 3 objects `a`, `lol`, and `b`.  You aren't tracking a copy constructor which is generated by the compiler (this one is called by  `lol`), so that's why there's only two constructors.

Answer (score 3):

It's being called once each for `a`, `lol`, and `b`.

To confirm this, you could add a field to the class, and assign each of them a name/id, which you print out in the destructor.  You  could also print out the value of `this`, which is a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SimpleClass lol = a;    //calls the default copy constructor which you have not defined
```

Override the copy constructor then you might see one new constructor called.

Answer (score 0):

You have `a`, `lol` and `b`.

Maybe you could print their addresses in `main()` and as well in the constructor and destructor, then you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Because destructor is the same for all objects.